# pink tif file made from ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, image-compression, fax

I am trying to send a tiff file through fax machine.

This file seems fine with image viewer and paint, but

my boss told me that while trying to send the tif file using fax program,

he's getting pink all over his background instead of white..

and 40 kb of tif file bumps up to 600kb while trying to send the tif file..

And I used ImageMagick converting from PDF to Tiff, and the command line I used was

"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/convert.exe" -density 200 -resize 1728x2291 -monochrome -compress group4 D://fax_files/201612/20161208155410.pdf D://fax_files/201612/example/1.tif

[the pink image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xhrL.jpg) is here..

Did I make any mistakes on using ImageMagick or are there any issues that cause the problem?

If you know any, please help me out..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that to fax a tiff, it has to be binary (black/white), not color and needs to be compressed with group 4 compression.

With PDF files you need to set the density and units before reading the input and all the other arguments afterwards.

So

```
convert -density XXX -unit YYY image.pdf -resize ZZZ -monochrome -compress group4 image.tif
```